# What is the concept of "down(up)scaling blocks" in neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I was trying to implement the training part of a paper and it says:
A discriminator Dsr (Rm) with 4 strided downscaling blocks is introduced.
In contrast to the well-known residual blocks, few things on it can be found via search engine, and I finally found something relative in [a blog](https://blog.csdn.net/yexiaogu1104/article/details/99757100) on notes of another paper:
[image: BRUH]

So is the down(up)scaling blocks here just a implementation, or are all down(up)scaling blocks like this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so now I found the solution to my own problem, but I hope someone can explain it more clearly:
Later in that paper, the author mentioned that:

> Specifically, The style extractor Est is a variational encoder consisting of 5 strided downscaling blocks and a fully connected layer, to map the reference input to a style vector.

And well, the author just didn't release training code and I'm implementing it, but the `The style extractor Est` is not a part of training code, so I looked into their implementation and located where `5 strided downscaling blocks` are created:
(If you want to see the full code here, go into their repo (ScreenStyle) and search class `E_NLayers`.)

```py
# some conditional codes are modified to its eqivalent when its condition is given
# nl_layer = get_non_linearity(layer_type='lrelu')
        kw, padw = 3, 1
        sequence = [spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(input_nc, ndf, kernel_size=kw,
                              stride=2, padding=padw, padding_mode='replicate')), nl_layer()]

        nf_mult = 1
        nf_mult_prev = 1
        for n in range(1, n_layers):
            nf_mult_prev = nf_mult
            nf_mult = min(2**n, 8)
            sequence += [spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(ndf * nf_mult_prev, ndf * nf_mult,
                         kernel_size=kw, stride=2, padding=padw, padding_mode='replicate'))]
            sequence += [nl_layer()]
        sequence += [nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(4)]
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(*sequence)
```

and spectral_norm is from:

```py
from torch.nn.utils import spectral_norm
```

Note: I prefer it to be written like this:

```py
        kw, padw = 3, 1
        sequence = [spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(input_nc, ndf, kernel_size=kw,
                    stride=2, padding=padw, padding_mode='replicate')), nl_layer()]
        nf_mults = ([1, 2, 4] + [8]*(n_layers-3))[:n_layers] # [1, 2, 4, 8, 8, 8, ...]
        nf_mults = zip(nf_mults[:-1],nf_mults[1:])
        sequence_more = [[spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(ndf * mult1, ndf * mult2, kernel_size=kw,
                          stride=2, padding=padw, padding_mode='replicate')), nl_layer()] \
                         for mult1, mult2 in nf_mults]
        sequence_more = sum(sequence_more, [])
        sequence += sequence_more
        sequence += [nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(4)]
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(*sequence)
```